# Is it possible to only install the package without dependecies?

Tags: debian, apt-get

I am trying to install texlive package, because that is the only package required to complete my compilation, but when I am installing using apt-get I am getting all the packages which are dependent on it, and making the size of my download to 282MB which I don't think I require. Could you please suggest how I can just download and install the particular package using apt-get.

Comment: It's highly probable that the package won't even build without its dependencies if they're software library dependencies.  It looks like texlive is itself a collection of other packages; if you can't download 282Mb, (I'm not sure if you're writing your own application or building someone else's) try downloading the individual components.

Comment: I am trying to compile emacs. :), but its more about knowing the possiblities.